# Correct typing for higher order function returning function with conditional interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How to correctly type following function?

1. `type` argument is provided, returns `requiredDpFields | null`
2. `type` argument is NOT provided, returns `requiredDpFieldsGroup | null`

```js
type ProfileTypeValues = 'personal' | 'company';

interface RequiredDpFields {
  require?: string[];
  requireOneOf?: string[][];
}
interface RequiredDpFieldsGroup {
  personal?: RequiredDpFields;
  company?: RequiredDpFields;
}

interface AppState {
  requiredDpFields?: Record<string, RequiredDpFieldsGroup>;
}

interface RequiredFieldsFn {
  (type: ProfileTypeValues, profileCountry?: string): RequiredDpFields | null;
  (type: undefined | null, profileCountry?: string): RequiredDpFieldsGroup | null;
};

function requiredDpFieldsHash(tld: string[], profileCountry?: string) {
  return tld.join(':') + ( profileCountry ? ':(' + profileCountry + ')' : '');
}

function requiredFields(state: AppState, getters: any): RequiredFieldsFn {
  const fn: RequiredFieldsFn = (type: ProfileTypeValues | undefined | null, profileCountry?: string) => {
    if (!state.requiredDpFields) {
      return null;
    }

    const hash = requiredDpFieldsHash(getters.tlds, profileCountry);
    const requiredDpFields = state.requiredDpFields[hash];

    if (!requiredDpFields) {
      return null;
    }

    return type ? requiredDpFields[type] || null : requiredDpFields;
  };
  return fn;
}
```

TS throws error on `const fn: ...`

```
Type '(type: ProfileTypeValues | undefined | null, profileCountry?: string | undefined) => RequiredDpFields | RequiredDpFieldsGroup | null' is not assignable to type 'RequiredFieldsFn'.
  Type 'RequiredDpFields | RequiredDpFieldsGroup | null' is not assignable to type 'RequiredDpFields | null'.
    Type 'RequiredDpFieldsGroup' has no properties in common with type 'RequiredDpFields'.
```

### EDIT 1

Trying overloads

problems:

1. As I need context of higher order function I put it inside, how to refer return value of higher order function now?
2. throws error

```
This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.
Type '(type: ProfileTypeValues, profileCountry?: string | undefined) => RequiredDpFields | null' is not assignable to type 'RequiredFieldsFn'. 
  Types of parameters 'type' and 'type' are incompatible. 
    Type 'null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ProfileTypeValues'. 
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ProfileTypeValues'.
```

```js
type ProfileTypeValues = 'personal' | 'company';

interface RequiredDpFields {
  require?: string[];
  requireOneOf?: string[][];
}
interface RequiredDpFieldsGroup {
  personal?: RequiredDpFields;
  company?: RequiredDpFields;
}

interface AppState {
  requiredDpFields?: Record<string, RequiredDpFieldsGroup>;
}

interface RequiredFieldsFn {
  (type: ProfileTypeValues, profileCountry?: string): RequiredDpFields | null;
  (type: undefined | null, profileCountry?: string): RequiredDpFieldsGroup | null;
};

function requiredDpFieldsHash(tld: string[], profileCountry?: string) {
  return tld.join(':') + ( profileCountry ? ':(' + profileCountry + ')' : '');
}

function requiredFields(state: AppState, getters: any): RequiredFieldsFn {

  function requiredFieldsFn(type: ProfileTypeValues, profileCountry?: string): RequiredDpFields | null;
  function requiredFieldsFn(type: undefined | null, profileCountry?: string): RequiredDpFieldsGroup | null {

      if (!state.requiredDpFields) {
        return null;
      }

      const hash = requiredDpFieldsHash(getters.tlds, profileCountry);
      const requiredDpFields = state.requiredDpFields[hash];

      if (!requiredDpFields) {
        return null;
      }

      return type ? requiredDpFields[type] || null : requiredDpFields;
  }

  return requiredFieldsFn;
}
```

### EDIT 2

[reproduction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=41&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewGYEsA2EAq4IDUCGaArhAM5QC8UA5JHKQgHaHVQA+NAxggLZj6MQ1ANwBYAFASUjYBDhJ8naACUIARyIo4EACYARMADEUENDvIBvCVCjaNWiAH4AXFFLA40gOYBtALpi4jZ2mtoA8owQYUgubh7e-v6BAL5SMnIKSlCq9tr6RiZmpADiiERgUFZBUHQMzGixOaG6Bsam5oE23HwCII3qzfltRSkSabLyitAAgmBgAMrA+LKV1rYDDkOF5v3ccDoAPO6ejF4ANNkbea3bJWVgAHyjkuLSE5kqV7rD5oaMq9UABSgSCueDIdBYHAEYhkC5gRCoDAAYQQRBkcD6rmO3gAlK4mpsbu1yBxGEQ0GhOlBgThXOidBBUJEdOwoOTKfDEZDUeiPFi4icvPjLrkWgUSaU0RUyRSqRJkoEJEh0ZxgCgmOsxVsSQAJfCkAAWwLM2Pip38XIhKLRGIFONOuIBwQgwCIcH+wDMADoAFYIaSA6jOahOgDUNJq3JtfMxUEcNGcQagEYR1ogvLtKZouNYrmooeeytV6s1IU2P1IgPcywgrlmCyWsguXldE1Irl6IsJeUrf2dUG4jHcUCQjAJXx0ff+VFpoNg0ahkBhJFJUAZTOkujZHLQVqRGdt-NiDuFlAeA5sKCQNIAhDXZN7y9cJUUnVUbJ-1m6Pey5dSbFSF4vyHEdDQNQ1KC1QZiSKfUjUBVtgHbb0vXMfceSPTFcQAwcmBHZ9xUrKCHwgJ9J1g8wfHAo0AjGaorxvQFb0InU30vT9tB-f5d1woC1hdbioBBaAE1YyjSB8ES-HYWVKSgVxxNfDo1kVNYuPdf4xxSIA)

[reproduction overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewGYEsA2EAq4IDUCGaArhAM5QC8UA5JHKQgHaHVQA+NAxggLZj6MQ1ANwBYAFASUjYBDhJ8naACUIARyIo4EACYARMADEUENDvIBvCVCjaNWiAH4AXFFLA40gOYBtALpi4jZ2mtoA8owQYUgubh7e-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-N29Fg2JRSl5UflIDtUNg2CgSA0gAhDWsjeuO4qVk6VQgch6xuh67JytSyGpC8KFQNwjDuFAhoGoalBat+EpFPqRqAq2wDtt6XrmM+MZ2riWEgQRRFwXu5jkdBECwbuP7mD4JFGgEYzASBYGQbxomkIhax4doaH-IenE2DhKkgWp7qejg8YUUSVFiSCEB+OwsqAa4ClmaQ1I6dU+nobxF4pEAA)

Comment: @jonrsharpe added example of overload usage

Comment: please share reproducable example

Comment: Try this signature: `(type: ProfileTypeValues | undefined | null, profileCountry?: string) `
Let me know if it work for you

Comment: @captain-yossarian thank you, I feel like I have tried the same thing, but maybe made some mistake on my first attempt, now it works correctly  

Comment: @captain-yossarian today I find out why it was magically working, as usual they weren't the same.. I putted there `any` instead of `AppState` as I thought it does not take effect on result. But actualy it does, so now after returning state type to `AppState` it is broken again, I have updated links in question.